# How to style the Winui 3 TabViewItem?

Tags: xaml, winui-3

There is nothing TabView or TabViewItem related in generic.xaml.

Where can the TabViews resource be found?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Windows UI Library repo](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/main/dev/TabView/TabView_themeresources.xaml)?

By using the keys there, you should be able to style your `TabView` exactly as you want, like so:

```
<TabView>
    <TabView.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ui:Color x:Key="BackgroundColor">#AAEEFF</ui:Color>
            <ui:Color x:Key="ItemHeaderBackgroundColor">#000000</ui:Color>
            <StaticResource x:Key="TabViewBackground"
                            ResourceKey="BackgroundColor"/>
            <StaticResource x:Key="TabViewItemHeaderBackground"
                            ResourceKey="ItemHeaderBackgroundColor"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </TabView.Resources>
</TabView>
```

Comment: I did see that repo and the TabView theme resources but it looked very basic, incomplete and was due to have parts retired. I will give it  go, thanks.